# Loading Multiple Tables using SSIS keeping foreign key relationships

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to load data from a single file (with million+ records) into multiple tables on SQL Server using SSIS while maintaining the relationships defined in the file.

To better elaborate with an example, lets assume I am trying to load a file containing employee name, the offices they have occupied in the past and their Job title history separated by a tab.

File:

```
EmployeeName<tab>OfficeHistory<tab>JobLevelHistory
John Smith<tab>501<tab>Engineer
John Smith<tab>601<tab>Senior Engineer
John Smith<tab>701<tab>Manager
Alex Button<tab>601<tab>Senior Assistant
Alex Button<tab>454<tab>Manager
```

If my Office database schema has the following tables:

```
Employee (nId, name)
Office (nId, number)
JobTitle (nId, titleName)
Employee2Office (nEmpID, nOfficeId)
Employee2JobTitle (nEmpId, nJobTitleID)
```

How can I use SSIS to load the file into the schema above Auto-Generating IDs for Employee, Office and JobTitle and maintaining the relationship between the employee and offices, and employee and Job Titles?

So in this case. the tables should look like:

```
Employee
1 John Smith
2 Alex Button

Office
1 501
2 601
3 701
4 454

JobTitle
1 Engineer
2 Senior Engineer
3 Manager
4 Senior Assistant

Employee2Office
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 4

Employee2JobTitle
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 4
2 3
```

I am a newbie to SSIS and have not played around with auto-generating IDs and establishing foreign key relationships while executing a Data Flow Task. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: My first question is how will your import know if two records with the same name are the same person or different people? Since names are not unique, you have to have a way in the file to know which is which.

Comment: Good question - Lets say we assume for this scenario, the employee name is unique. So there will be only one John Smith in this organization.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting question.  Here is how I would do it (Sql Server 2005). (I'm assuming this is a monthly job and not just a one time, so I added code for repeatability.)

1. Create three variables for the Employee, JobTitle and Office table (type = Object)
2. Use three sql tasks to select the rows for of those three tables into the corresponding variables.
3. Add a dataflow task.
4. Select from your flat file using a flat file destination.
5. Output goes into a script component with the three columns in the flat file as input, the three table variable imported into the script, five outputs in the script component each with the same exclusion group number and the input marked as synchronous for that output, seven new columns (3 for emp one for each output it will be in, 2 for job, 2 for office) added to the output, and with the following code (A Reference to System.xml.dll had to be added to make this all work.):

   ```
   Imports System
   Imports System.Data
   Imports System.Math
   Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper
   Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper
   Imports System.Collections
   Imports System.Data.OleDb

   Public Class ScriptMain
       Inherits UserComponent

       Private da As New OleDbDataAdapter
       Private emp As New DataTable
       Private emph As New Hashtable()
       Private job As New DataTable
       Private jobh As New Hashtable()
       Private off As New DataTable
       Private offh As New Hashtable()
       Private maxempid As Integer
       Private maxjobid As Integer
       Private maxoffid As Integer

       Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
           maxempid = 0
           maxjobid = 0
           maxoffid = 0
           da.Fill(emp, Me.Variables.EmpTab)
           For Each dr As DataRow In emp.Rows
               emph.Add(dr.Item("Name"), dr.Item("nID"))
               If (CInt(dr.Item("nID").ToString) > maxempid) Then
                   maxempid = CInt(dr.Item("nID").ToString)
               End If
           Next
           da.Fill(job, Me.Variables.JobTab)
           For Each dr As DataRow In job.Rows
               jobh.Add(dr.Item("titleName"), dr.Item("nID"))
               If (CInt(dr.Item("nID").ToString) > maxempid) Then
                   maxjobid = CInt(dr.Item("nID").ToString)
               End If
           Next
           da.Fill(off, Me.Variables.OffTab)
           For Each dr As DataRow In off.Rows
               offh.Add(dr.Item("number"), dr.Item("nID"))
               If (CInt(dr.Item("nID").ToString) > maxempid) Then
                   maxoffid = CInt(dr.Item("nID").ToString)
               End If
           Next
           emp.Dispose()
           job.Dispose()
           off.Dispose()
           da.Dispose()
           MyBase.PreExecute()
       End Sub

   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       If Not emph.ContainsKey(Row.EmployeeName) Then
           maxempid += 1
           emph.Add(Row.EmployeeName, maxempid)
           Row.EmpId = maxempid
           Row.Emp2Id = maxempid
           Row.Emp3Id = maxempid
           Row.DirectRowToEmployee()
       Else
           Row.EmpId = CInt(emph.Item(Row.EmployeeName).ToString)
           Row.Emp2Id = CInt(emph.Item(Row.EmployeeName).ToString)
           Row.Emp3Id = CInt(emph.Item(Row.EmployeeName).ToString)
       End If
       If Not jobh.ContainsKey(Row.JobLevelHistory) Then
           maxjobid += 1
           jobh.Add(Row.JobLevelHistory, maxjobid)
           Row.JobId = maxjobid
           Row.Job2Id = maxjobid
           Row.DirectRowToJobTitle()
       Else
           Row.JobId = CInt(jobh.Item(Row.JobLevelHistory).ToString)
           Row.Job2Id = CInt(jobh.Item(Row.JobLevelHistory).ToString)
       End If
       If Not offh.ContainsKey(Row.OfficeHistory) Then
           maxoffid += 1
           offh.Add(Row.OfficeHistory, maxoffid)
           Row.OffId = maxoffid
           Row.Off2Id = maxoffid
           Row.DirectRowToOfficeNumber()
       Else
           Row.OffId = CInt(offh.Item(Row.OfficeHistory).ToString)
           Row.Off2Id = CInt(offh.Item(Row.OfficeHistory).ToString)
       End If
       Row.DirectRowToEmp2Job()
       Row.DirectRowToEmp2Off()
   End Sub        
   End Class
   ```
6. The results from this script (The script generates id's for new values in the input data.  It does this by loading up the existing table into hashtables in the preexecute portion of the script, then by checking for existance of the name and based upon that either increments the maxid and adds it to the hash if it adds to the hash, it also adds the row to the appropriate (emp, job, or off) output, or retrieves the maxid from the hash for each row.) all row regardless of status above will be written to the two remaining outputs (emp2job and emp2off).
7. Next, send dataflows to lookup (to check for existing rows in the destination table, then the destination oledb connectors (the emp, job, and off check the box for identity inserts, the emp2job and emp2off uncheck check constraints).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your referential integrity is OK with the data that you want to load, you can disable foreign key constraints in a Script Task, then execute data flow with parallel data load and after data load finishes, enable the constraints again. If there is something not right with the data, the operation will fail. You will have to design rollback or cleanup strategy though.

The other option is just to load data in serial way, starting from main tables and finishing on child tables. I think this is 'safer' option, as it doesn't expose your data integrity to other users who may be using these tables at the time of ETL load. I would prefer this option.

Comment: For the first option, how do I establish the mappings in Employee2JobTitle and Employee2Office after I load the data? 

Exposing data to users is not a relevant issue in my world - The second option will be time consuming for large data sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how - it's slightly difficult to explain in text only, but I'll give it a shot:

Define the employee, office and job title tables in your database with an identity column, so that IDs will be generated automatically.

Define the many-to-many tables without (identity is not needed or useful)

In your SSIS data flow, you have to do this in a couple of passes, in order to establish the IDs in the database first, then come back and insert the many-to-many rows.

Make one data flow:

1. Put a data source to read in the file
2. Split it into three copies with a Multi-Cast. One will be for employees, one offices, one titles.
3. For each, put a Sort (this is generally a no-no, but since the source is text and not a database, we have to go there). Set the sort to pass through only one of the three fields, and check the option in the sort to remove duplicates. This makes a unique list (like select distinct) for each base table.
4. Put a destination for each of the three, connected to each table.

After the first data flow, add a second data flow. This one will populate the many-to-many relation rows

1. Read the file with a data source
2. Add a lookup that finds for Employee Name in the database and returns the Employee ID. That gets you the Employee ID that was generated above. (this is usually called lookup by business or natural key for surrogate key)
3. Add a lookup that finds for Title in the database and returns the Title ID
4. Add a lookup that finds for Office in the database and returns the Office ID
5. Again, multi-cast the results into two copies, one for employee-office and one for employee-title
6. Depending on the logic you need, perhaps use Sort, again, to deduplicate these (depends on the detail of how you are normalizing from the input)
7. Put the results into the many-to-many tables with two destinations.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a stored procedure that first insert data in basic tables (employee,office and JobTitle) then read your file row by row. after that you should search your basic tables for getting the Identities and insert data to relation tables.