# Reference foreign keys using SSIS-Lookup

Tags: merge, ssis, lookup, data-warehouse, ssis-2019

I am asking for help on the following topic. I am trying to create an ETL process with two Excel data sources (S1 ~300 rows and S2 ~7000 rows). S1 contains project information and employee details and S2 contains the amount of hours, which each employee worked in which project at a timestamp.

***I want to insert the amount of hours, which each employee worked in each project at a timestamp, into the fact table by referencing to the existing primary keys in the dimension tables. If an entry is not present in the dimension tables already, i want to add a new entry first and use the newly generated id.*** The destination table structure looks as follows (Data Warehouse, Star Schema):[Destination Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Wbx.jpg)

In SSIS, i created three Data Flow tasks for filling the Dimension Tables (project, employee and time) with distinct values (using group by, as S1 and S2 contain a lot of duplicate rows)first, and a fourth data flow task (see image below) to insert the FactTable data, and this is where I'm running into problems:

[Data Flow Task FactTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Y5s.jpg)

I am using three LookUp functions to retrieve the foreignKeys project_id, employee_id and time_id from the Dimension tables (using project name, employee number and timestamp). If the id is found, it is passed on all the way to *Merge Join 1*, if not, a new Dimension Entry is created (lets say project) and the generated project_id passed on instead. Same goes for employee and time respectively.

There is two issues with this:

1) The "amount of hours" (passed by Multicast four, see image above) is not matched in the final result ([No Match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3TNh.jpg))

2) The amount of rows being inserted keeps increasing forever ([Endless Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTZWB.jpg), I belive due to the Merge joins).

What I've tried:

- I have used one UNION instead of three Merge Joins before, but this resulted in the foreign keys being in seperate rows each, instead of merged together.
- I used Merge (instead of Merge Join) and combined the join as well as sort conditions in as I fell all possible ways.

I understand that this scenario might be confusing for everybody else, but thank your for taking time looking at it! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll probably need to add some more details before we can help you. How are your Lookups, Merge Joins, and Script Tasks configured?

Comment: I doubt you have an endless join happening here. I would guess that your Merge Join  #3 is not correctly matching records and you've ended up creating a CROSS JOIN that will produce ~40 million records (9855 x 4062 = 40031010).

Comment: thanks for your comment. yes, it defenitely wasn't an endless join, but it felt that way :-) my approach was a little of from the start, I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it

For anybody having similar issues:

Seperate Data Flows for filling Dimension Tables with those filling Fact Tables will do the trick.
Its a clean solution and easier to debug.

Also: Dont run the LookUp Functions in parallel, but rather one after each other and pass on the attributes. Saves unnecessary Merges as well.

So as a Sum Up:
Four Data Flow Tasks, three for filling dimension tables ONLY and one for filling fact tables ONLY.

[Loading Multiple Tables using SSIS keeping foreign key relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211840/loading-multiple-tables-using-ssis-keeping-foreign-key-relationships)
The answer posted by *onupdatecascade* is basically it.

Good luck!